# How to remove this "colapse class button" in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I just want to get rid of this colapse button, want a clear view in my text editor. Can´t find this in options!

[image: that line]

Comment: Turn off outlining.

Comment: @RetiredNinja thanks!! I love the new versions that are more simple and intuituve

Comment: Why would you want to do that though? Being able to fold and focus only on certain parts of the code is one of the big advantages of using an IDE instead of WordPad ^^

Comment: @derHugo Preference. The first thing I do in any editor is turn off outlining. I hate it.